# powershell + oh my posh + pure theme - what is the disk glyph means in git directory

Tags: git, powershell, windows-terminal, oh-my-posh

in powershell with oh my posh installed and the [pure](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/themes#pure) theme activated, when the working tree is clean, I see a floppy disk glyph with a number after it like the picture below:

[image: disk glyph in git directory]

Anyone knows what the disk glyph and the number beside it means?

Comment: Remember the SO community rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- ***[Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)*** --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) --- [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: This is not a PS code issue, it's an environment config concern. Each of the OMP themes has complete docs for them, and what the glyphs/symbols mean. [What did you search for from those repositories?](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/git) similar questions are on SO, where others are using similar themes. So, your question is a duplicate of those similar queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the amount of `git stashes` you have. In this case, you've got two stashes which should display when typing `git stash list`.